# SPARQL Query in Protege for identifying data property assertion value

Tags: sparql, protege

I have a question about SPARQL Query in Protege

I have a built ontology. This ontology includes a subclass called `HVAC_CL`. `HVAC_CL` subclass contains an individual called `AirCondition_CL`. `AirCondition_CL` as an individual is assigned to a Data property called `InstallationPrice`. The data property assertion for `InstallationPrice` is `4000` (as an integer value).

I need a SPARQL Query in Protege to identify the `InstallationPrice` of the `AirCondition_CL` individual.

Comment: and you tried what? I mean, it's the most basic SPARQL query containing just a simple triple pattern that matches the RDF triple `(s p o)` - so if you know what subject, predicate and object is in your case (which is trivial), then you know what you have to replace by a variable which you in the end want to return, i.e. `SELECT`

Comment: Please provide sample data, and expected outcome.

Comment: The ["How To Ask" article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be helpful...

Comment: Dear AKSW I am a recent protege user, could u help me with this SPARQL Query